# Multidimensional Array to Single Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, $result, which outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => boyzerooooo [0] => boyzerooooo ) [1] => Array ( [username] => mynameiszero23 [0] => mynameiszero23 ) [2] => Array ( [username] => yournameiszero [0] => yournameiszero ) [3] => Array ( [username] => zerotolerance [0] => zerotolerance ) )
```

I use the following function, to turn it into a one dimensional array:

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}
```

Which then outputs to:

```
Array ( [username] => zerotolerance [0] => boyzerooooo [1] => mynameiszero23 [2] => yournameiszero [3] => zerotolerance )
```

My problem is that zerotolerance is being outputted twice, and I'm not sure why. When I use `foreach` to output the array, zerotolerance is outputted twice. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_unique` and `array_values`..

```
return array_unique(array_values($result));
```

---

The `array_values` returns all the values from the array and the `array_unique` returns only the unique values from the array.

Comment: :D Thank you, can you explain your answer? It works. I'll accept your answer when I can.